# Using flask-admin, how can I get a tag field supporting un-existed tags?

Tags: python, flask

I got two models Product and Tag, and set many to many relationship in SQLAlchemy.
Using this as the flask-admin examples shows:

```
 admin.add_view(ProductAdmin(db.session))
```

I get a create form, and can only select existed tags.
I know the flask-admin is using select2, and select2 gets a style of add new tags.
And I found class Slect2TagsField in Form.py under the flask-admin folders.

So, how can I get a tag field, which supports adding new tag, in my product create form, by using flask-admin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, Flask-Admin does not support inline tag creation, because there's no AJAX endpoint which can register new tags.

Comment: Thanks, Joes. But why there is a Select2TagsField class in form.py under the flask-admin folder? Can I use this to implement a inline tag creation function? Thanks.

Comment: Right now it is used for PostgreSQL Array data type. Also can be used manually for non-SQL backends like pymongo/mongoengine with nested lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Flask-Admin does not expose any AJAX endpoints, so it is not possible to create new models in Select2 fields.

However, there's way to make it work:

1. Exclude tags field from the admin form
2. Contribute new Select2TagsField to the form with different name (so there's no name collision)
3. Before displaying new/edit view, serialize list of tags as string array and contribute to the Select2TagsField
4. Before submitting model (on_model_change) go over the list, do database lookups to find existing tags and create models for missing tags
5. Contribute list of tag models to the model

Comment: It's too complex for me ,I am new to python ,sorry...
I have written my admin pages by myself, flask-admin is great and easy  for normal models.

Comment: did you ever get around to creating that gist?

Comment: Did you ever get around to creating that gist?  I'm pretty confused.

Comment: More like people get lazy and want ready to use solution. Answer is fully sufficient - all you need is to add custom logic to handle values that were sent to the server and create necessary models in on_model_change method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `TagField` and add it to your `ModelView.` You will have to override some field functions.

**I have put together a [demo application](https://github.com/ix5/flaskadmintagdemo) that uses select2 version 4 and is a bit more detailed than this answer.**

The tag field:

```
class CustomTagField(Select2TagsField):

    widget = CustomTagWidget(multiple=True)

    def pre_validate(self, form):
        pass

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            self.data = []
            for tagname in valuelist:
                rv = Tag.query.filter_by(name=tagname).first()
                if rv:
                    self.data.append(rv)
                else:
                    self.data.append(Tag(name=tagname))
        else:
            self.data = []

    def iter_choices(self):

        self.blank_text = ""

        tags = list(set([str(tag.name) for tag in Tag.query.all()]))
        model_tags = [tag.name for tag in self.object_data]

        self.choices = [[tag, tag] for tag in tags]

        # Yield empty object in order to have an empty placeholder
        yield (u'__None', self.blank_text, self.data is None)

        for value, label in self.choices:
            yield (value, label, value in model_tags)
```

Custom widget: (similar to `Select2TagsWidget`, but does not set `data-role` so `form.js` will not make it a regular select2 field)

```
class CustomTagWidget(widgets.Select):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('data-tags', '1')
        # Or call select2 in tags mode

        allow_blank = getattr(field, 'allow_blank', False)
        if allow_blank and not self.multiple:
            kwargs['data-allow-blank'] = u'1'

        return super(CustomTagWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

In your admin:

```
form_extra_fields = {
        'tags': CustomTagField(
            'Tags',
        ),
}
```

Then override your admin template to call select2 in tag mode on your field(`admin/js/form.js` will try to style the field as well):

```
$('#tags').select2({
  tags: true,
});
```